# How to use localStorage to save variable with random value

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to use localStorage to save a variable with value generated randomly from an array in a JavaScript file, and pass it to another HTML file. However, the value in Javascript file (`Random_Msg`) and the value in HTML file (`Random_Msg1`) are not the same, means it's not saved, instead it generated randomly another value.

These are the code to generate variable and save in localStorage:

```
function CreateRandomMsg(){
var RandomMsg = Msgs_Arr[Math.floor(Math.random()* Msgs_Arr.length)];
return RandomMsg;
}

var Random_Msg = CreateRandomMsg();

function alertMsg(){
alert(Random_Msg);
}
window.localStorage.setItem("Random_Msg1",Random_Msg);
```

In my HTML file, I just retrieved the variable first:

```
var Random_Msg1 = window.localStorage.getItem("Random_Msg1");
```

And use it in if statement:

```
if (Random_Msg1 == Msgs_Arr[0] || Random_Msg1 == Msgs_Arr[1]){
     value = facesDet.photos[0].tags[0].attributes.glasses.value;
     confidence = facesDet.photos[0].tags[0].attributes.glasses.confidence;
    } else if (Random_Msg1 == Msgs_Arr[2] || Random_Msg1 == Msgs_Arr[3]) {
      value = facesDet.photos[0].tags[0].attributes.smiling.value;
      confidence = facesDet.photos[0].tags[0].attributes.smiling.confidence;
    };
```

Comment: When you save on first page, you can check its value in dev tools. Check if what you  save is saved properly or not. Also, you can only write strings in localStorage, so if you try to write an object, `[object Object]` would be written.

Comment: @Rajesh I finished testing, local storage works fine, but the variable will change when it loads to HTML page, thus the variable changes. How should I save the variable on refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check on `pageload` if value for necessary key exists in `localStorage`. If value is missing, then compute and save new value. You can also have an extra event on which you can override value of this key, but this will be a user action.

**Note:** *Stack Overflow does not give access to `localStorage` and any testing should be done on JSFiddle.*

#### Sample

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qjvx8yyr/1/)

```js
function computeRandomValue() {
  var data = ["test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) % data.length;
  return data[index];
}

function setToLocalStorage(newVal) {
  var lsKey = "_lsTest";
  localStorage.setItem(lsKey, newVal);
}

function getFromLocalStorage() {
  var lsKey = "_lsTest";
  return localStorage.getItem(lsKey);
}

function initializePage() {
  var _val = getFromLocalStorage();

  if (!(_val && _val.trim().length > 0)) {
    _val = computeAndSaveNewValue();
  }

  printValue(_val, "lblResult");
}

function computeAndSaveNewValue() {
  var newVal = computeRandomValue();
  setToLocalStorage(newVal);
  printValue(newVal);
  return newVal;
}

function printValue(value) {
  var id = "lblResult";
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
}

(function() {
  window.onload = initializePage;
})()
```

```html
<p id="lblResult"></p>
<button onclick="computeAndSaveNewValue()">Save new Value</button>
```